# Railo and Tomcat - where is the root directory

Tags: tomcat, railo, turnkeylinux.org

I have installed TurnKey Tomcat and deployed a Railo WAR. The default www directory does not seem to recognize .cfm files but notice that 192.168.91.128/railo  is using a .cfm file. Is Railo and Tomcat root dependent on the extension. Where do I need to deploy .cfm files or how can I change the www to work with .cfm?

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat doesn't support ColdFusion by default since it isn't part of Java EE specification. If you want to deploy cfm files on Tomcat you need install ColdFusion first. I have found the following links:

- http://www.andyallan.com/blog/post.cfm/installing-an-configuring-coldfusion-9-01-on-tomcat-7
- http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/j2ee/phase2-tomcat-deploy.html

Please check the version of ColdFuion that you need.

**EDIT:**

Apparently you have Railo installed (ColdFusion Engine) my suggestion is that you review the documentation at http://www.getrailo.org/. From this site I have found the following:

> First is is important to know that the architecture in Railo is
>   different than in other CFML engines. In Railo configuration can be
>   made either per web context level or per global context. Now what is a
>   web context?
>
> **What is a web context?** 
>   A web context is a secured area provided by the application server (and NOT by the webserver). A web context is
>   defined by a  entry in the corresponding configuration file of
>   the application server. These files differ from app server to app
>   server. In Resin for example this file is called resin.conf or
>   resin.xml, whereas in Tomcat it is called server.xml. Please check the
>   corresponding documentation of your application server in order to see
>   how to define these web contexts.
>
> The fact that you define new web contexts in the application server is
>   the reason why any definition of a new website in the webserver can
>   only be defined differently on a web context basis if you have
>   mirrored the configuration of the webserver in the application server
>   by using virtual host definitions.

Comment: I am actually following this link and it is not Coldfusion but Railo.

Comment: http://henke.ws/post.cfm/developers-guide-to-turnkey-tomcat-  apache-with-coldfusion-engines